# Why can't sqlite find this row?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite3. My test table contains two rows (see screen dump image), but I can not find the second row using the

> SELECT * FROM test WHERE word="id"

statement. Why can't sqlite find that row?

(I think the problem is that one attribute is also called "id",  because I have found that the select statement would work if that attribute where named `id2` instead.)

[image]

Comment: it's easier for us to help you if you copy/paste instead of giving a screenshot ;-)

Comment: Okay, next I do that time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because of the double quotes, using single quotes will have it work fine:

```
sqlite> create table test ( id integer primary key autoincrement, word text not null unique on conflict ignore );
sqlite> insert into test values (1, 'xxx');
sqlite> insert into test values (2, 'id');
sqlite> select * from test;
1|xxx
2|id
sqlite> select * from test where word = "id";
sqlite> select * from test where word = 'id';
2|id
```

and this is because `id` is the name of a column in your current schema, as you can use double quotes around column names, sqlite thinks you're talking about columns, not giving a string. i.e.:

```
sqlite> insert into test values (3, 3);
sqlite> select * from test where word = "id";
3|3
sqlite> select * from test where word = id;
3|3
```

if you can use double quotes on columns, it's because spaces are legal in column names:

```
sqlite> create table test2 ( "foo bar" integer );
sqlite> .schema test2
CREATE TABLE test2 ( "foo bar" integer );
sqlite> insert into test2 values (42);
sqlite> select * from test2;
42
sqlite> select * from test2 where "foo bar" = 42;
42
```

Comment: because single quotes is what is used in the language to define a string! With double quotes, sqlite3 will first look up for names in the table, and only then consider it as a string.

Comment: "if you can use double quotes on columns, it's because spaces are legal in column names". I don't think this statement is accurate. Double quotes are meant to indicate an identifier which could be a table name or a column name. This fact doesn't depend on spaces being allowed in column names.

Comment: double quotes are not mandatory for table/column name identifiers in SQL, and the only case they're _necessary_ AFAICT it's when an identifier contains a whitespace character. Though, I'm only assuming that fact based on logic, it's not something I read somewhere. That same logic applies in shell scripting argument passing : if you have two tokens they're two strings, if you surround them with quotes, it's a single string.